# Toggling a text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I toggle a .text() between "+" or "-" at the start of the li ***(when clicked)***? It's for the expanding object at the very bottom of http://flatfilthy.se/dominic/

```
$(function(){
   $(".vaccordian li.expander").on('click', function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
   });
});
```

Comment: I don't see a "+" or "-"

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish this with a bit of CSS, for example:

```
li.expander:before {
    content: '+';
}

li.expander.active:before {
    content: '-';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".vaccordian li.expander").on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).text(function(oldtext) {
        var first = oldtext.substr(0, 1);
        return (first == "+" ? "-" : "+") + oldtext.substr(1);
    });
});
```